# Transformar (o pivotear) atributos de una fila en columnas en R

Tags: r, pivot

espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Estoy trabajando con datos desde archivos xml, de autores de articulos cientificos, quisiera saber, he intentado con `pivot_wider(names_from = ID,names_prefix = "autor_" ,values_from = surname)` de dplyr, pero el resultado no ha sido satisfactorio.

Mi df:

```
    ID surname  
   <dbl> <chr>    
 1     1 ALBORNOZ 
 2     1 LORCA    
 3     1 PERSICO  
 4     2 ARANDA   
 5     3 ARRIAGADA
 6     3 COHEN    
 7     4 AVILA    
 8     5 AVILA    
 9     6 ASHWORT  
10     6 HARVEY
```

Lo que quiero:

```
    autor_1     autor_2  autor_3  
[1,] "ALBORNOZ"  "LORCA"  "PERSICO"
[2,] "ARANDA"    NA       NA       
[3,] "ARRIAGADA" "COHEN"  NA       
[4,] "AVILA"     NA       NA       
[5,] "ASHWORT"   "HARVEY" NA
```

Desde ya agradezco sus aportes y sugerencias!

Con la ayuda de `user:31764` llegué a está solución

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col_name=paste("author",row_number(),sep="_")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=ID, names_from=col_name, values_from=surname)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
     ID author_1 author_2 author_3 author_4 author_5  author_6 author_7 author_8 author_9 author_10
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 ALBORNOZ LORCA    PERSICO  NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       
2     2 NA       NA       NA       ARANDA   NA        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       
3     3 NA       NA       NA       NA       ARRIAGADA COHEN    NA       NA       NA       NA       
4     4 NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       AVILA    NA       NA       NA       
5     5 NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA       AVILA    NA       NA       
6     6 NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       ASHWORT  HARVEY
```

Es bueno, pero quisiera dejar la fila 2 debajo de `autor_1` y así sucesivamente. De todas forma la solución es casi perfecta!

Answer (score 2):

Con `dplyr` solo te haría falta generar el nombre de la columna para cada fila, de la siguiente forma:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(col_name=paste("author",row_number(),sep="_")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=ID, names_from=col_name, values_from=surname)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [6]
     ID author_1  author_2 author_3
  <int> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 ALBORNOZ  LORCA    PERSICO 
2     2 ARANDA    NA       NA      
3     3 ARRIAGADA COHEN    NA      
4     4 AVILA     NA       NA      
5     5 AVILA     NA       NA      
6     6 ASHWORT   HARVEY   NA
```

Comment: Los resultados aparecen en 11 columnas, hacia la derecha, y necesito que se agrupen hacia abajo, se parece pero no es lo mismo, muchas gracias, esto hice `df %>% 
  mutate(col_name=paste("author",row_number(),sep="_")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=ID, names_from=col_name, values_from=surname)`

Comment: Si un ` ID` tiene 11 filas, te aparecerán 11 columnas, no puedo decirte mucho más por que debería ver los datos reales. Lo que sí me he dado cuenta que en tu ejemplo tienes dos AVILA con distinto ID, esta solución te los va a mostrar separados.

Comment: Ok, entiendo la lógica y me anda bien, pero quisiera lograr que se ordenaran hacia abajo y no hacia la derecha. los AVILA distintos está bien porque tienen distinto id, tal como quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta una variable en el data.frame que indique un consecutivo por cada libro. Algo así:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6)
surname <- c('ALBORNOZ', 'LORCA', 'PERSICO', 'ARANDA', 'ARRIAGADA', 'COHEN', 'AVILA', 'AVILA', 'ASHWORT', 'HARVEY')
autor <- c(1,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,2)
df <- data.frame(ID, autor, surname)
```

De ese modo se puede usar el comando reshape()

```
df2 <- reshape(df, idvar = 'ID', v.names = 'surname', timevar = 'autor', direction = 'wide', sep = '_')
```

Y queda tal como lo espera.

Comment: Exacto! el tema es que la data es muy grande y debo automatizar ese proceso, necesito una forma transformar `ID` en `autor` en los términos planteas en tu ejemplo, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: El sitio tiene la política de que se contesta una cosa a la vez. Debe realizar una pregunta respecto a cómo automatizar la asignación de autor según los ID de los libros.